# Converting JToken into .NET types with custom SerializerSettings

Tags: .net, json, json.net

Json.NET separates the JSON parsing from the construction of .NET objects. In particular should

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyType>(jsonString)
```

be the same as

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JToken>(jsonString).ToObject<MyType>()
```

The `ToObject` method has no parameter that takes a `SerializerSettings` though. So how do I specify JSON converters and related settings?

Comment: JToken is one of the classes used by JsonConvert.Deserialize. Whatever `ToObject()` does, `JsonConvert.Deserialize<JToken>` is wrong. Use `JToken.Parse(myJsonString)` at least

Comment: I guess the answer to "should `code` be the same as `code`?" is no, it should not.

Comment: `How do I specify type converters and related settings?` [TypeConverter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.typeconverter?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2)  is a .NET attribute that's applied to a class. It's not specific to JSON.NET, although JSON.NET will use it if available. Are you asking how to use a custom Json Converter perhaps? You can create a custom one and apply it using the [JsonConverter](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverterAttribute.htm) attribute to a class or property

Comment: @John this looks like an XY problem. What is the *actual* question you want to ask? Do you have a complex property that you'd want to serialize in a specific way? Have you check the [ 
Serializing and Deserializing JSON](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingJSON.htm) section in the documentation ?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Uh? How is that wrong? And what about `JToken` properties, is something wrong about that too?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Because a) explaining the real problem is five times as much text, b) I'm pretty good at seeing all the paths I can potentially go so I don't need that and c) it makes for much better question/answer pairs for other people who come here from google. (You're right about the json converter, I updated the question.)

Comment: @John this question hasn't gotten any answers because people are still trying to guess what it asks. `Deserialize<JToken>` doesn't make sense. much less following it by `ToObject()`. `ToObject` doesn't accept any serializer settings because it doesn't deserialize anything. Deserializing *and* mapping to a concrete class is the job of `Deserialize`, which [does accept serialization settings](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_DeserializeObject__1_2.htm)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have already parsed your JSON into a `JToken` hierarchy, you can use [`JToken.ToObject<T>(JsonSerializer)`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_ToObject__1_1.htm) to deserialize to your desired type using your converters:

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    Converters = { new MyTypeConverter() },
    // Other settings as required.
    DateTimeZoneHandling = DateTimeZoneHandling.Utc, 
};
var myType = jToken.ToObject<MyType>(JsonSerializer.CreateDefault(settings));
```

Note that Json.NET handles `DateTime` and floating-point recognition during string tokenization, so if you split your JSON deserialization into two stages, `string` ⇒ `JToken` ⇒ `MyType`, then date strings and decimals may get parsed and recognized prematurely.  You may need to specify appropriate settings while initially parsing your JSON and/or defer date recognition like so:

```
var parseSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.None, // Defer date/time recognition until later.
    FloatParseHandling = FloatParseHandling.Decimal, // Or Double if required.
};
var jToken = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JToken>(jsonString, parseSettings);
```

(In contrast, when deserializing directly from a string to a POCO without an intermediate `JToken` representation, the serializer can pass "hints" to the [`JsonTextReader`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonTextReader.htm) tokenizer as to whether certain primitive tokens should be interpreted as dates, decimals or whatever by using the [`ReadType`](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/JsonTextReader.cs#L37) enum.  Thus enumeration is, however, internal to Newtonsoft.)

For more on `DateTime` parsing see *[Serializing Dates in JSON](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DatesInJSON.htm)*.  Sample fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ReJWvE).